# Working out integration of basic signal functions

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, homework, self-study

As the title suggests , I'm having problems working out the integration of some basic signal functions. Shown below are the questions and my workings. For some reason I'm just unable to get the answer.

For a) and c) , I know that for u(t) is basically 0 before t=0 , thus I changed the limits for the integration. I did the same thing for u(t-1)

Thanks for the help!

[image: Questions]

[image: Workings]

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  I've added tags of `homework` and `self-study`. Please feel free to delete one or the other of them if they are inaccurate.

Comment: Any chance for TeX formatting?

Answer (score 1):

So you've already figured out the $u(t-T)$ trick:  the unit step (delayed) just changes the limits of integration.

The other trick is that $\delta(t-T)$ just "samples" the value of the rest of the integral's argument. So, for example, $\int x(t) \delta(t-T) dt = x(T)$ where $T$ is somewhere within the integral's limits.

Comment: I tried using that for c) , assuming that T=0 , but I still am unable to get the correct answer.

Comment: Well, that's the other trick: note I said "where $T$ is somewhere within the integral's limits".  If $T$ is **not** within the integral's limits then $\int x(t) \delta(t-T) dt = 0$.

Comment: But if I assume T=0 , then it is obviously within the integral limits.

Comment: Are you telling me that $T=0$ is within the integration limits of $\int_{1}^T \cos(t)\delta(t) dt$?

Comment: I'm confused , the integration limits for that question are from 1 to infinity. Knowing that T=0 , it obviously fits.

Comment: Are you telling me that 0 is between 1 and $\infty$ ?

Comment: Oh gosh , I missed it out. Sorry that was a stupid mistake. But that won't help much for (b).

Comment: (b) is the same: your integration limits **must** contain $T$ in $\delta(t-T)$. Note that the upper integration limit is $t$.  What happens if $t<0$?

Comment: If t<0 , then the integration result would be 0. From 0 to t , the result would just be an integration from 0 to t of cos(τ). Which just gives me sin(t) , how does it reduce to u(t)?

Comment: Well, no.  if $t<0$ then you are correct.  If $t>=0$ then the sampling option happens and it evaluates to $\cos(0)$.

Comment: Oh right. and cos(0) = 1. But evaluating the integral would only give me t , not exactly a unit step function yet.

Comment: Why would it give you $t$? $\int_{-\infty}^t \cos(\tau) \delta(\tau) d\tau = \cos(0) = 1$ for $t\ge 0$ and $0$ for $t\lt 0$.  Which is, by definition, $u(t)$.

Comment: My mistake. I mixed up the formula for the sifting property of the dirac delta function. Finally , for (d) , I can apply the same concept , but what do I do about the extra "t" in front of the sin function?

Also , for (a) , I believe my working is correct , but why is there an extra u(t) in the answer? My guess is to make sure that the signal should be 0 from t<0 onwards. Since the original function before integration was cos(t)u(t) , integrating 0 still gives 0.

Comment: (a) is the same issue as (b): there is an implicit $u(t)$ based on whether $t$ is greater than or less than 0.  (d) The extra $t$ is just sampled like the everything else: provided the integral limits contain $\pi$ (in this case), you sample the function at $\pi$.  The integral limits **have** to include the $T$ when there is a $\delta(t-T)$ there for the sampling to work; otherwise the value is zero.

Comment: I understand how to get (d) now. But for (a) , I have already changed the limits of the integration and therefore can substitute u(t) with 1. So it should not even appear in the integration result.